# PHP Calculate the remaining time from Login and logout in minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP. I have a login system where i am storing the login and logout time in database. My database table is

```
id        username      password     logintime                            logouttime
1            test                 test           2014-08-24 13:45:07       2014-08-24 13:45:17
2            test1               test2         2014-08-24 13:55:07       2014-08-24 13:55:37
```

and using a function i am trying to find the difference between the login and logout time difference in minutes. I tried like

```
function mytest ($login, $logout, $remaining)
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE logintime ='$login' AND logouttime = '$logout'");
$retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
    {
        $remaining = $login - $logout;
        echo $remaining;
    }

}
```

but cannot find the result. Please help me in finding out the time difference between two in minutes using function. I surfed for the whole day but couldn't find answer.

Comment: shouldn't you be using timediff function of mysql which will directly give you the difference

Comment: @Satya i would like to calculate the remaining time using a my function and like to show the input in minutes

Comment: then change this line $remaining = $login - $logout; to $remaining = date_diff($logout, $login); echo  $remaining->format('%R%i minutes');

Comment: @Satya i tried this but it returns nothing

Comment: try this  $remaining = date_diff(strtotime($logout), strtotime($login));

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$logout = strtotime("2014-08-24 13:45:17");
$login = strtotime("2014-08-24 13:45:07");
$diff=$logout-$login;
echo round($diff/60)." minutes ".($diff%60)." seconds";
```

output

> 0 minutes 10 seconds

Comment: hey I have been searching and your solution gets me a little closer to some thing ... how would you calculate the following 
days , months and years difference ... it would be really help full

Comment: @noufalcep here i don't want to specify my date and time explicitly, instead i would like to use database values in a variable

Comment: @SmartWorker so what's the problem .. put variables instead of the datetime string.. strtotime($datetime);

Comment: Use $logout=strtotime($logout) and $login=strtotime($login)